# angular 2 *ngFor how to acces value

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have pb with angular 2

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of elements">
   <h1>  {{elm["0"].value}}</h1> 
</div>
```

how i can acces to value of "elm" if it is an array ?
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `"0"` as your key you're implying that you're working on an `object` instead of an `array`, because `arrays` can't have string literals as a key in javascript.

So you want to access it with a `number` instead:

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of elements">
   <h1>{{elm[0].value}}</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: No, this would be an `object` not an array.  For example `myArr = []; myArr['test'] = 'test'` would lead to an error, while `myArr = {}; myArr['test'] = 'test'` would not. The first one is an array, the last one an object (which you could use as a dictionary or 'associative array'.

Answer (score 2):

If `elements` is an array of arrays:

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of elements">
    <h1>{{elm["0"]}}</h1> 
</div>
```

This assumes that the value of `elm["0"]` is string or number. If `elm["0"]` is an object that has a string/number property called `value` then use `elm["0"].value`.

Answer (score 0):

If the elm is an array you could access like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of elements">
   <h1>  {{elm[0]}}</h1> 
</div>
```

But this also works:

```
<div *ngFor="let elm of elements">
       <h1>  {{elm["0"]}}</h1> 
</div>
```